# What functional group is this in this specific molecule?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I know without the nitrogen this molecule would probably be considered a crown ether. What exactly would the nitrogen/oxygen functional groups be named as in this molecule shown below? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Molecule]

Comment: replacement nomenclature will always work.

Comment: Well, compound is substituted hydroxylamine, not ether.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to get an idea of what it would be called to look up relevant research on functional groups like this.